# Making Skype for Business Portable

Tags: windows-7, portable, thin-client, skype-for-business

Our company is going to be switching most of our section to thin clients without skype for business (despite skype for business being so needed for our job, they want us accessing it via a terminal server which is... less than ideal. I know regular skype has a portable version, but is there a way to get skype for business to be portable so we can just run it from a flashdrive?

Comment: If you install the requirements for Skype for Business, and you copy the application directory, does it work on the thin client?

Comment: @ramhound I can definitely try that... will have answer tomorrow.